# react redux fetching secondObject using data from first fetchedObject

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I have several objects that I get using react redux.
Each Object has its one slice and reducers where it is being fetched.
Second Object must be fetched according to the data taken from the first fetched Object.

In my react component I use useEffect to get first object while page is being loaded for the first time.

```
useEffect(() => {
 getFirstObject(dispatch);
},[]);
```

My problem is that then after the FirstObject is fetched and accessible on the page I want to start fetching data for the second slice object using data from the firstObject. I can do that using useEffect again

```
useEffect(() => {
 getSecondObject(firstObject.someData,dispatch);
},[firstObject]);
```

because firstObject changes it will be triggered. But I have several more such objects to fetch and I don't want to reload the whole page several times until all objects will be fetched
How can I do that in Redux style without using another useEffect and not reloading the whole page ? I have read about redux thunk, redux saga and other things. But did not quite got what are they made for and if they can help me solve my problems. What is the best practice way in this situation ?

Comment: probably you can just create a promise, and then call the second function

something like ```getFirstObject().then(firstObjectData => getSecondObject(firstObjectData))```

Comment: unfortunatelly that do not work, cause firstObjectData is fetched async and is not returned straight here getFirstObject(). 
inside first object slice redux assigns data fetched to some object. that is accessible through store on page. and when I use .then and try that object it is in initial state. at that time not loaded